# How do I print a specific sublayout in Sitecore?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I want to print a specific sublayout in Sitecore when a asp:HyperLink (or else asp:button) is pressed. I have the print device and print layout configured in the sitecore. How do I make use of it to print the sublayout pointed by the print device? Please explain with a sample code if you know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Sitecore Content Editor, you can configure the Detection in /sitecore/layout/Devices/Print. By default you can add the querystring ?p=1 behind the URL of the item you want to print.

Comment: I have already done that. My question is how do I use it to print the page when a user presses a button.

Comment: Something like `hyperlink.NavigateUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl + "?p=1"` ...

Comment: Only thing to add here is if the Url already contains query parameters you want to append `&p=1` instead, easy to do that check though

Comment: Thank you @ThomPuiman. This worked. I added OnLoad="javascript:window.print();" inside the body tag, I wrote a javascript function that creates a new window which goes to the url you mentioned and I called this function onclick.